# Create grid-like Image3D

Tags: image, image3d

I would like to create a visualization of a volume with the help of equally-spaced grid lines. The effect I want to get is easily obtainable for 2D images, the image is simply divided into quadratic patches and the boundary is replaced by some constant value:

```
patchSize = 10;
insidePad2D[x_, padding_, val_] := 
 With[{offset = padding + 1}, 
  ArrayPad[x[[offset ;; -offset, offset ;; -offset]], padding, val]]
dataSpikey = ColorConvert[Import["ExampleData/spikey.tiff"], "Grayscale"] // ImageData;
imgSpikey = ArrayFlatten[BlockMap[insidePad2D[#, 1, 0] &, dataSpikey, {patchSize, patchSize}], 
   2] // Image
```

[image]

However, this seems to be more challenging for `Image3D`:

```
patchSize = 10;
insidePad3D[x_, padding_, val_] := 
 With[{offset = padding + 1}, 
  ArrayPad[x[[offset ;; -offset, offset ;; -offset, 
    offset ;; -offset]], padding, val]]
dataEngine = Import["ExampleData/CTengine.tiff", "Image3D"] // ImageData;
dataEngine = 
  ArrayFlatten[
   BlockMap[insidePad3D[#, 1, 0] &, 
    dataEngine, {patchSize, patchSize, patchSize}], 3];
imgEngine = Image3D[dataEngine]
```

[image]

The grid lines are visualized as zero-opacity voxels ("gaps") and not in black as desired. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to come very close to what I wanted. The trick is to apply the color function **before** the data is given `Image3D`. This way black voxels can be added as desired and the internal color function doesn't mess with it.

```
f = Blend[{{0., RGBColor[0.05635, 0.081, 0.07687, 0.00343663]}, {0.1, 
     RGBColor[0.8877, 0.2636, 0., 0.103093]}, {0.3, 
     RGBColor[1., 0.6036, 0., 0.302406]}, {0.66, 
     RGBColor[1., 0.9658, 0.4926, 0.661168]}, {1., 
     RGBColor[1., 0.6436, 0.03622, 1.]}}, #1] & (* Default color function of Image3D *)
dataEngineF = Map[f, dataEngine, {-1}];
dataEngineF = 
  ArrayFlatten[
   BlockMap[insidePad3D[#, 1, RGBColor[0, 0, 0, 0.01]] &, 
    dataEngineF, {patchSize, patchSize, patchSize}], 3];
Image3D[dataEngineF]
```

[image]